# The class of the element change using the javascript

Tags: javascript, html

currently I am trying to implement the change in the class of the element using javascript, and currently the problem is that when i press on the home page, the last page does not get disselected.
my javascript code is

```
 var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
 var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
 var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
 var home = document.getElementById("Home");

 home.onclick= function () {
   for (var i = 0, j = contactPage.length; i < j; i++){
     if(homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")){
        homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");            
     }
   }
   home.classList.add("current-page");
}
```

my DOM elements

```
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="about-page">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="contact-page">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

what could be the issue? how to improve?

edit:
i did use the code that day

```
   var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
    var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
    var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
    var home = document.getElementById("Home");

    homepages = [contactPage ,aboutPage, home];

    home.onclick= function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
            if(homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")){
            homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");
            
        }
        }
        home.classList.add("current-page");
    

    }
    aboutPage.onclick = function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
            if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
            homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

                }
            }
            aboutPage.classList.add("current-page");

        }
        contactPage.onclick = function () {
                for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
                    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
                        homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

                    }
                }
                contactPage.classList.add("current-page");

            }
```

however run into this issue:
[image]

Comment: Your code does not show `homepages` being defined.

Comment: @RobMoll my bad, it was defined in my actual file though. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this line:

```
for (var i = 0, j = contactPage.length; i < j; i++){
```

should be:

```
for (var i = 0; j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++){
```

Or better yet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length - 1; i++){
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate:

```js
var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
var home = document.getElementById("Home");

homepages = [contactPage, aboutPage, home];

home.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length - 1; i++){
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  home.classList.add("current-page");
}
```

```css
.current-page {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="about-page">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact-page">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are heading down a path where you are going to duplicate `onclick` functionality by copying code blocks numerous times for each of the links shown.

You can make the whole thing generic with one click event listener on the `<ul>` and query for the current page class to remove it and add the class to the target of the event

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('#nav');

nav.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   // remove current claass from whichever element already has it
   nav.querySelector('.current-page').classList.remove('current-page');
   // add current class to  element that was clicked
   e.target.classList.add('current-page');
   // use the id to do some conditional logic if needed
   console.log('Selected =',e.target.id) 
})
```

```css
#nav a.current-page{color:red}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="about-page">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact-page">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just only compare i with the array length. It's should be like this

```
 var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
 var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
 var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
 var home = document.getElementById("Home");

 home.onclick= function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < contactPage.length; i++){
     if(homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")){
        homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");            
     }
   }
   home.classList.add("current-page");
}
```

But I think you have to make sure about where `contactPage` and `homepages` come from

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your goal, but if you want to move "current-page" class between links, you could use **forEach()** in JavaScript:

```js
var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
var home = document.getElementById("Home");

homepages = [contactPage, aboutPage, home];
let currentPage;

homepages.forEach(element => {

    if (element.classList.contains("current-page")) {
        currentPage = element;
    }

    element.onclick = function() {

        if (element !== currentPage) {
            removeClassAll();
            element.classList.add("current-page");
            currentPage = element;
        }
    }
});


function removeClassAll() {
    homepages.forEach(elem => {
        elem.classList.remove("current-page")
    })
}
```

```css
.current-page {
color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="about-page">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="contact-page">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems like after I have edited the code the class on the last element did not delete

Comment: If you use only the code that I put there it works for moving class between links, but if you combined some other codes to it, maybe it causes some problems.